# Can't initialize a variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to write a simple program for converting currency rates.But I cannot assign a value to double.Here is the error code    Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression status
Error C4700 used uninitialized local variable "grn" Twice D: \ programs \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ repos \ Twice \ Twice.cpp 12

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
double  usd;
double  grn;
cout << "Enter in usd :";
cin >> usd;
usd = grn / 27.29;
cout << usd << " here is usd " << " = " << "to grn" << " grn \n";
}
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `grn`. So `usd = grn / 27.29;` and `cout << ... << grn` are undefined behavior. You also never appear to define `dollar`.

Comment: where is `dollar` defined?

Comment: dollar there are usd i am already fixed it.But the error remained...

Comment: If you've already fixed it, edit the question to show the code that only has the errors that still remain.

Comment: I have already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have declared `dollar` variable.
In Your code `grn` doesnt have any value so output can be always 0.

Answer (score 0):

You've read the value of **usd** using the cin `cin >> usd` and on the next line you are overwriting the value of **usd** using  `usd = grn / 27.29` and grn value is never assigned any default value. 
 
Either the formula should be `grn = usd /27.29` or you need to use `cin >> grn`.

Answer (score 0):

you variable `grn` doesn't have a value assigned to it so it would give an error

Answer (score 0):

You declared usd and take input with "cin" But you had not assigned any value to grn.
So you need to use **cin>>grn** to assign value to grn while executing the program.
And then use usd = grn/27.29 ; To convert it into usd.